# Group elements of an array of objects on the basis of some conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as follows :

```
array = [
{
 "id":1,
 "type":"abc",
 "quantity":36,
 "code":"EDF",
 "period":"2023-04-01"
},
{
 "id":0,
 "type":"yrf",
 "quantity":40,
 "code":"SFDF",
 "period":"2023-04-02"
},
{
 "id":0,
 "type":"yrf",
 "quantity":22,
 "code":"SFDF",
  "period":"2023-04-02"
},
{
 "id":1,
 "type":"abc",
 "quantity":19,
 "code":"EDF"
 "period":"2023-04-01"
}
]
```

For any two elements in the array, I want to combine the elements if `period`, `type` and `code` are the same. For those elements, if `id` is `1` then, then the value of `quantity` should be set to a new attribute, `quantity_{{code}}_cy`. If `id` is `0`, then the `quantity` of that element should be set to `quantity_{{code}}`. For example, for the above array, my final array should look like:

```
finalArray=[
{
 "id":1,
  "type":"abc",
 "quantity_EDF_cy":36,
 "code":"EDF",
  "quantity_EDF":''
 "period":"2023-04-01"
},
{
 "id":0,
 "type":"yrf",
 "quantity_SFDF_cy":'',
  "quantity_SFDF":22
 "code":"SFDF",
 "period":"2023-04-02"
}
]
```

Here for `EDF`, the first and last elements have the same `type` (`abc`), the same `code` and the same `period` and the `id` is `1`, so it is eligible for the addition of new attributes `"quantity_EDF_cy": 36` and `quantity_EDF": ''` -- this should be empty for `id` `1` and if `id` is `0` then `"quantity_EDF_cy":''` should be empty. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: [related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76091550/grouping-elements-of-array)